# covering subsets

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, combinatorial-designs

Let $A=\left\{ {1, 2,  \ldots, n}\right\}$. 
Let $B$ be the set of all size $m$ subsets of $A$.  $B=\left\{{B_1,B_2, \ldots , B_{\binom{n}{m}} } \right\}$, $  |B_i|=m$
then we want to find $k$ subsets of $A$, each of size $r$, (let call them  $C=\left\{{C_1,C_2,\ldots,C_k}\right\}$, $|C_i|=r$ ), so that for any $B_i$, there exists at least one $C_j$ in $C$ so that the intersection of $B_i$ and $C_j$ is empty.

Example, 
if $n=7$, $m=3$, $r=2$, 
then with $k=7$ subsets we can build $C$ as follows:
$C=\left\{
{\left\{ {1, 2}\right\},
\left\{ {2, 3}\right\},
\left\{ {3, 4}\right\},
\left\{ {4, 5}\right\},
\left\{ {5, 6}\right\},
\left\{ {6, 7}\right\},
\left\{ {7, 1}\right\}}\right\}$

which has the property that for any subset of $A$ of size $m=3$, denoted by $B_i=\left\{{b1,b2,b3}\right\}$,  there is at least one $C_j$ in $C$, that has no intersection with $B_i$.

The question is given $n$,$m$, and $r$, what is the minimum $k$ for which a corresponding $C$ exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you replace the sets $C_j$ by their complements $C_j'$, then each $B_i$ must be contained in some $C_j'$.  This is called a *covering design.*  The [La Jolla Covering Repository](https://www.dmgordon.org/cover/) is a great place to look.

Comment: @hardmath thanks!